# React hook get triggered on closing sidebar of streamlit when using React D3 component( https://github.com/andfanilo/streamlit-d3-demo)

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, d3.js, streamlit

i am using useEffect hook to re-render graph when data is changed as shown below

```
const svgRef = useRef(null)
const { svgWidth, svgHeight, data, line_data, key }: PythonArgs = props.args

useEffect(() => {
       Chart()
       .container(svgRef.current)
       .data(data)
       .render()
   }, [])


   // Hook to update data
   useEffect(() => {
       Chart()
           .container(svgRef.current)
           .data(data)
           .render()
   },[data])
```

but whenever i click on close button the hook gets triggered.

Attached is the screenshot of sidebar.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first hook.
Modify the second as following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (data && svgRef.current) {
    Chart().container(svgRef.current).data(data).render();
  }
},[data, svgRef]);
```

Does it help?

Comment: thanks for the answer. But i had to use JSON.stringify(data) to make it work